# Data Quality Scan in Dataplex with Python library

Tags: data-quality, google-dataplex

[Publish results to BigQuery and Dataplex Catalog UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV6UU.png)
I am configuring the creation of Data Quality scan using the python library to interact with the Dataplex API (dataplex_v1). I need, when creating a scan, to configure the option to have the results published in BigQuery and Dataplex Catalog UI. Does anyone know how to do it?

I saw this option but I understand that what it does is to save the results as records in a table in bigquery, what I need is to show the scan in the DATA QUALITY section of my table ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDA1K.png)).
`data_profile_spec { post_scan_actions { bigquery_export { results_table = "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/my-project-name/datasets/dataplex_dataset/tables/profile_export" } } }`

Comment: Hello, I've the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API support for publishing to BigQuery and DataCatalog UI yet.
This API support will be available in Q1 2024.
In the meanwhile, you can create the Datascans via python client SDK and use the UI to publish the results to BQ and DataCatalog UI.

Comment: How it is going ?